# how can i upload image using react native expo image to my local server PHP / Database MySQL

Tags: php, reactjs, database, react-native, expo

I'm making a mobile application using expo client to allow user to upload image or take from a camera and then the image saves on my local server on PHP / Database MySQL. How do I do that thing if I'm using an expo?

for example code in react native (saving to PHP local server but not save database)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  Button,
  Clipboard,
  Image,
  Share,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    image: null,
    uploading: false,
  };

  render() {
    let {
      image
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />

        <Text
          style={styles.exampleText}>
          Example: Upload ImagePicker result
        </Text>

        <Button
          onPress={this._pickImage}
          title="Pick an image from gallery"
        />

        <Button onPress={this._takePhoto} title="Take a photo" />

        {this._maybeRenderImage()}
        {this._maybeRenderUploadingOverlay()}
      </View>
    );
  }

  _maybeRenderUploadingOverlay = () => {
    if (this.state.uploading) {
      return (
        <View
          style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, styles.maybeRenderUploading]}>
          <ActivityIndicator color="#fff" size="large" />
        </View>
      );
    }
  };

  _maybeRenderImage = () => {
    let {
      image
    } = this.state;

    if (!image) {
      return;
    }

    return (
      <View
        style={styles.maybeRenderContainer}>
        <View
          style={styles.maybeRenderImageContainer}>
          <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={styles.maybeRenderImage} />
        </View>

        <Text
          onPress={this._copyToClipboard}
          onLongPress={this._share}
          style={styles.maybeRenderImageText}>
          {image}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  _share = () => {
    Share.share({
      message: this.state.image,
      title: 'Check out this photo',
      url: this.state.image,
    });
  };

  _copyToClipboard = () => {
    Clipboard.setString(this.state.image);
    alert('Copied image URL to clipboard');
  };

  _takePhoto = async () => {
    const {
      status: cameraPerm
    } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);

    const {
      status: cameraRollPerm
    } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);

    // only if user allows permission to camera AND camera roll
    if (cameraPerm === 'granted' && cameraRollPerm === 'granted') {
      let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3],
      });

      this._handleImagePicked(pickerResult);
    }
  };

  _pickImage = async () => {
    const {
      status: cameraRollPerm
    } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);

    // only if user allows permission to camera roll
    if (cameraRollPerm === 'granted') {
      let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3],
      });

      this._handleImagePicked(pickerResult);
    }
  };

  _handleImagePicked = async pickerResult => {
    let uploadResponse, uploadResult;

    try {
      this.setState({
        uploading: true
      });

      if (!pickerResult.cancelled) {
        uploadResponse = await uploadImageAsync(pickerResult.uri);
        uploadResult = await uploadResponse.json();

        this.setState({
          image: uploadResult.location
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log({ uploadResponse });
      console.log({ uploadResult });
      console.log({ e });
      alert('Upload failed, sorry :(');
    } finally {
      this.setState({
        uploading: false
      });
    }
  };
}

async function uploadImageAsync(uri) {
  let apiUrl = 'http://192.168.0.18/upload-api/uploading.php';
  let uriParts = uri.split('.');
  let fileType = uriParts[uriParts.length - 1];

  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('fileToUpload', {
    uri,
    name: `fileToUpload.${fileType}`,
    type: `image/${fileType}`,
  });

  let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  };

  return fetch(apiUrl, options);
}
```

and here is my PHP

```
  <?php
   $target_dir = 'uploads/';
   $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);

   $status = array();

   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
   $status['status']=1;
   $status['description']='upload success';
  } else {
   $status['status']=0;
   $status['description']='upload failed';
  }
   echo json_encode($status);

  ?>
```

Any solution to this? thank you

Comment: You could use [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy) to upload an image to your database.

Comment: ok. if i'm using yarn? is it still can upload to my server?

Comment: yarn is just a package manager. You have to set up the backend to upload it to your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Fetch Api](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network.html#using-fetch) to upload image

```
var photo = {
  uri: selectImg.localUri,
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  name: 'photo.jpg',
};

var form = new FormData();
form.append("ProfilePicture", photo);

fetch(
  Constants.API_USER + 'me/profilePicture',
  {
    body: form,
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.token
    }
  }
).then((response) => response.json())
.catch((error) => {
  alert("ERROR " + error)
})
.then((responseData) => {
  alert("Succes "+ responseData)
}).done();
```